# How can i calculate percent end time when below .exe is running on ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, security, visual-studio-2013

I want to press button and it should continue and display percent time when i click another page, code should on background. After that i click this page it display me results belong running .exe process. 
How can i do that? I need your help.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
Process p = new Process();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.Arguments = "/Scan http://localhost/deneme/sunucu.html /Profile web_applications /SaveToDatabase –ScanningMode=Heuristic –UseAcuSensor=TRUE –EnablePortScanning=TRUE";
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Acunetix\\Web Vulnerability Scanner 9.5\wvs_console.exe";
p.StartInfo = startInfo;
p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("received output: {0}", args.Data);        
p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
StreamReader output = p.StandardOutput //i tried beginoutputreadline
p.WaitForExit();        
ListBox1.Items.Add(output.tostring());
```

Regards,